# erro permissao git local

Tags: git

Estou com problema travado já no 2º dia. Não consigo commitar arquivos no meu sistema.

Erro encontrado durante a publicação para o repositório remoto:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Falha ao enviar o branch por push para o repositório remoto. Consulte a 
Janela de Saída para obter mais detalhes.

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Tentei usar só `push`:

```
git push
```

Ele pediu caminho especifico: `git remote add <name> <url>`

Usei:

```
git push origin master
```

tentei usar essa tag:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Não funcionou.

Desinstalei. Reinstalando tinha uma referencia a SSL. Pensei que era isso, pois pesquisando vi em algumas respostas falando sobre isso.

Mas não foi. Alguém sabe como resolvo esse problema local na minha maquina.

Comment: Erro comum com quem está iniciando. Tenha certeza de ter usado `git init` e adicionar o repositório remoto `git remote add origin https://github.com/seu-usuario/repo`

Comment: mas é local D:\Tec\Dev\GIT_REPORTORIOS ou C:\Users\Documents\projeto
Eu nao inseri essa tag. Devido a isso o erro?

Answer (score 3):

Tenta assim:

`git init` - Para iniciar o repositorio local;

`git remote add nome-repositorio-remoto end-repositorio-remoto` - Para indicar o endereço do repositório remoto;

`git push nome-repositorio nome-branch` - Isto fara com que você envie uma branch(nome-branch) para seu repositorio remoto(origin).

Exemplo:

```
$git init
$git remote add origin https://tonidev@bitbucket.org/tonidev/bootstrap4.git
$git push origin master
```

EDIT 1: Repositórios(bare) locais

Você pode, por exemplo, precisar de autenticação para acesso de leitura ou pode exigir mais velocidade do servidor. Para cada uma dessas escolhas, há um protocolo recomendado. O Github, por exemplo, provê acesso de leitura para os repositórios públicos via protocolo git (mais leve e rápido). Mas para acesso de escrita dos commiters do projeto, usa SSH (um pouco mais pesado, mas provê autenticação). Outra opção é HTTP para leitura, que facilita atravessar firewalls corporativas.

Enfim, há basicamente quatro opções:

- Mapeamento local
- SSH
- Protocolo próprio do git
- HTTP

O que você vai escolher (ou se vai optar por uma solução híbrida, como o Github) depende das suas necessidades.

Com o comando `git init --bare` você está criando um repositório que é *pushable*. Geralmente os repositórios bare são criados no servidor e são considerados repositórios para armazenamento, em contraste aos repositórios que vão nas máquinas dos desenvolvedores que seriam os repositórios de desenvolvimento, criados com o comando `git init` (sem o `--bare`).

Apesar do GIT ser um sistema de controle de versionamento distribuído, é muito comum que exista um repositório central que facilite a troca de informações entre os desenvolvedores, evitando a necessidade que os computadores dos desenvolvedores se comuniquem diretamente entre si.

Além do mais, repositórios bare não possuem *working directory*, tornando impossível editar e commitar arquivos nesse repositório.

*Mas para o seu caso:*

criando estrutura de repositórios no HD Externo

```
mkdir repositorios
cd repositorios
mkdir nome_projeto
cd nome_projeto
```

o comando abaixo cria um repositório remoto, deve ser rodado dentro do HD Externo

```
git init --bare
```

criando repositório local e enviando para o remoto

```
git init
```

fazer o commit inicial "-a" vai adicionar todos os arquivos no commit e "-m" permite vc acrescentar um comentário ao commit.

```
git add .
git commit -a -m 'comentário'
```

gravando o endereco do HD Externo para vc nao ter que ficar digitando sempre

```
git remote add hdexterno /caminho-do-hdexterno/caminho-repositorio/caminho-projeto
#se precisar remover
git remote rm hdexterno
```

atualizando o hdexterno

```
git push hdexterno
```

para clonar um projeto do hd externo na sua maquina

```
git clone /caminho-do-hdexterno/caminho-repositorio/caminho-projeto
```

pegando novidades do hd externo e atualizando na maquina

```
git pull hdexterno
```

Comment: Usei o remote add nao deu certo
C:\Users\Documents\projeto\ git remote add origin  D:\Tec\Dev\GIT_REPORTORIOS
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Adicionei um arquivo na minha pasta clone para commitar e quando dei push o erro foi seguinte:
 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To  D:\Tec\Dev\GIT_REPORTORIOS
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to ' D:\Tec\Dev\GIT_REPORTORIOS'
C:\Users\Documents\projeto\

Comment: Cara, fiz uma edição na minha resposta, espero que ajude!

Comment: obrigado, vou te dar um review da situacao C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users//Documents/projeto/x/.git/
PS C:\Users\\Documents\projeto\x> git status
On branch master
No commits yet
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

(texto.txt)
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
PS C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git add *
PS C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git commit -m "1 commit"
[master (root-commit) c2f3081] 1 commit
 1 files changed,  insertions(+)

Comment: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Users\ext.jasuris\Documents\projeto\x> git log
commit c2f30819194e3c8cd45136d802e6cf102b246cf3 (HEAD -> master)
Author: jr <email@email.com.br>
Date:   Thu Jul 5 11:34:41 2018 -0300
1 commit

Comment: Aqui que esta o grande problema impressionantem mas nao consigo resolver esse o erro
C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x>  git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslbackend=schannel
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.name=jr
user.email=email@email.com.br

Comment: gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/ext.jasuris/Documents/x/testeGIT
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/ext.jasuris/Documents/projeto/x
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
PS C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x>

Comment: Peguei caminho de um servidor externo deu mesmo erro de permissao :/  :                       
 - fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Tem teamviewer?

Comment: È pela empresa vou tentar fazer o mesmo procedimento em casa e posto o feed aqui, ams nao so comigo outro deve tambem mesma coisa quando vai dar push em qq brunch no meu caso ate local da o erro:[C:\Users\Documents\projeto\x> git push origin master fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.]